# Migration to ColdFusion 9 - Element is Undefined Error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am hoping I can get an answer to this. We recently migrated a ColdFusion site to a new server, which has ColdFusion 9. The older server had 7 on it, maybe 8.  Everything was working find on the old system. Now, I get the Element Undefined Errors.

The Application.cfm (not .cfc) is in the webroot where it always was. There is no Application.cfc file.

Here is a screen shot of the Application dump: 
[image]

Here is a sample page with the error: http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/listings/send_message.cfm?id=26552

So, in the screenshot above, there is the captchaseed, etc., but when it tries to call it - it says it's undefined.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!  I am sure this is something easy, but I've never done this migration before, so have no idea why it won't work.

**ADDED FROM THE COMMENTS**

In the Application.cfm, located in the web root, there is the following:

```
<cfset APPLICATION.captchaseed = 'ACDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXY34679'>
```

Here is a [link to the screen shot](http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/ss.png) with the `cfdump`.

Here are a few examples of the undefined errors for reference: http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/listings/send_message.cfm?id=31820
http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/newsletter_box_action.cfm

Comment: So I take CAPTCHASEED is defined in application.cfm? If yes, the where is it defined.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  In the Application.cfm, located in the web root, there is the following:

<cfset APPLICATION.captchaseed = 'ACDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXY34679'>

Comment: Try Debugging Through application.cfm. So when you hit the url, put a dump of application object right after the CAPTCHASEED definition and see if it is hitting till there. And then Put some debugs around requests functions

Comment: I'll be honest - I have no idea how to do that. Is there a specific code I can put in there to try?  I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: `<cfdump var="#application#" abort>`

Comment: Ok, I put in that code, and it started giving me a different message when loading the site - so obviously - it sees the Application.cfm file along with the application captchaseed and others that are causing the error.  So now what can I do? (I took out the code to bring the site back online)

Comment: did it output a structure of information? If it didn't then it's not correct.

Comment: Yes, it did. It shows the captchaseed, along with newsletterslist, that is also an error that appears saying it is "undefined".

Comment: add a screenshot of the dump to your post. If it's showing the data it can't also say it's undefined.

Comment: Here is the screen shot: http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/ss.png

Comment: Here are a few examples of the undefined errors for reference:
http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/listings/send_message.cfm?id=31820
http://www.luxurylifestyle.com/newsletter_box_action.cfm

Comment: Can you put all these further details into the question, rather than in cooments and off-site images.

Comment: I updated the problem... but since I am new - it won't allow me to post images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we've got enough to answer this yet, but let's try.

Can you check your file system between send_message.cfm and the Application.cfm in your root directory, and check if there's any other Application.cfm in between.

Also check for any `<cfapplication>` tags in any of the files making up the request.

Can you also check your code for anything that might be clearing the application scope, or elements in it.

Can you also pls put a try/catch around the line that's erroring, and dump out the application scope at *that* point.

I suspect you have a second being initialised somewhere during your request which is overwriting the one you're expecting.  This is, currently, just speculation.

I'll update this answer as more info comes in.

Comment: I updated the problem... but since I am new - it won't allow me to post images.

That said - everything was working perfectly on the old server. Not a single character of code has been changed. So, my guess is the problem lies within a server setting?

Comment: This issue has been solved.

There was a code inside of the Application.cfm file, which is the following:

    <cfapplication setclientcookies="false" sessionmanagement="true" name="test">

We are unclear exactly why this code was put in many years ago when the programmer originally created the site - but taking this code out made everything work.

Maybe someone can post a comment on exactly why in ColdFusion 9 this created a problem - when in CF 8 there was none?

Comment: Well you need a CFAPPLICATION tag to create the application in the first place. You oughtn't be able to use application variables without one. I dunno why your code works on EITHER version of CF, TBH.

Comment: Hate to say it, but it is probably possible to declare a structure named "application" that is actually part of the `variables` scope. ie `variables.application`. I am not saying that is what is happened, but .. it is the only way I could see it working without a cfapplication tag. (Though maybe they meant something totally different, like there were *multiple* `cfapplication` tags, or Application.cfm files, involved and removing one of them resolved the issue?)

Comment: @Leigh, yeah, I was concerned that might have been happening. BUt as you say, not easy to tell based on the info provided. Still: there's no reason this ought to change behaviour between CF8 & CF9 though. I think there's more info here than we are getting.